# AWS S3 minimum object storage of 128KB - does it makes sense to sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My initial plan for using S3 as a backup storage was to use AWS CLI and `aws s3 sync` my directories into the AWS cloud (almost the same as you would do a normal `rsync`). But know I read, that AWS S3 has a minimum object storage of `128KB` what means that I would end up paying for `128KB` for each file which is smaller than that - which is not less when syncing a whole server.

Because I'm new to backing up with AWS S3 I decided to ask here: What is the best strategy to backup with S3? Does it make sense to `sync` or should I pack my files on the server into a tarball, `gzip`/`xz` the tarball, encrypt it and upload it to S3 instead? How do you guys do that in plans of backing up servers?

Comment: What kind of files are these? How often do they change?

Comment: Let's say a standard Linux system, where you want to backup `/etc`, `/var/www`, `/home`, `/root`, etc.

Comment: Then go with `git`, or other VCSes. Most of the files would be text. If you want to stick with AWS solution; it has Code Commit which provides free tier for indefinite time period: https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/pricing/

Comment: Yes, I use `git`, but I can not upload everything to it. I think I'll write some script and go with the tarball alternative.

Comment: Why not? If the repository is hosted privately, isn't this the same as syncing data on s3?

Comment: Yes you're right, but I had to create a repository for each single folder in my gitlab, what would mess up the structure. Also I would had to take care of all commits and pushs to gitlab, so anyway I had to write some script.

Comment: The 128K minimum is only for Infrequent Access storage; if you use standard storage you can have objects of any size. Yes, you'll pay approximately 1 cent more per gigabyte to do this.